# Facing problems going back to django 1.9 from 1.10

Tags: django

I am trying to learn django through a tutorial Try Django 1.9. I installed django version 1.10

I am trying to uninstall 1.10 and install 1.9

I uninstalled using pip. Then went into site packages and cleared the django folders.

I even searched for django and deleted all possible file. But when I tried to install django version 1.9, the Power Shell (or terminal) started collecting django from the cache and reinstalled django 1.10.

How do I clear the cache?

Comment: Pip will only install what you ask for. Exactly what did you type to install 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

Try `--no-cache-dir` option to pip